# Cygwin scp command read as incomplete

Tags: cygwin, scp

I am trying to copy a file from a remote server to my local Windows machine using Cygwin. Here the command I am using:

```
userMe$ scp username@111.11.111.111:~/Desktop/O'Bryan/file.csv  ~/
```

On enter, the system returns a pipe:

```
userMe$ scp username@111.11.111.111:~/Desktop/O'Bryan/file.csv  ~/
>
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe in "O'Bryan" opened a string and the command is waiting for the closing quote.  You can escape it (\') to avoid this from happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your shell is interpreting the quote `'`. You need to escape it with double quotes `"'"`, or a slash `\'`. I recommend attempting to avoid the use of `'` in file names.

```
 scp username@111.11.111.111:~/Desktop/O\'Bryan/file.csv  ~/
```

or

```
 scp username@111.11.111.111:~"/Desktop/O'Bryan/file.csv"  ~/
```

or

```
 scp username@111.11.111.111:~/Desktop/O"'"Bryan/file.csv  ~/
```

More info: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html
Read everything at the grymoire site. It may be old, but it is great info and written in an engaging way.